# react-leaflet with original leaflet plugins

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet

It is more theoretical question, rather than some problem.
I'm planning to develop some wrapper for leaflet (encapsulate work with leaflet for other developer teams with some API in/out), and I'm wondering if to use react-leaflet or to use native leaflet library.

There is very long list of available plugins for leaflet, and as far as i see only +-10 of them implemented for react-leaflet.

From your experience, does all the original leaflet plugins works fine with react-leaflet? How often do you encountered with problem and which one are not working at all?

Comment: if you are use SSR check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51265189/react-leaflet-map-error-in-server-side-rendering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible to create a [custom component](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/docs/Extending.md#creating-custom-components) for any react-leaflet extension.