# react leaflet map error in server side rendering

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, react-leaflet, react-starter-kit

**RESOLVED --- please read update 2**

hello I've this error in react starter kit with react-leaflet map

it's like github module example but i dont know what is problem!!! i think it have a problem with SSR

react version: 16.x and react starter kit

**UPDATED 1**

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at D:\project\react-starterkit\node_modules\leaflet\src\core\Util.js:217:24
    at version (D:\project\react-starterkit\node_modules\leaflet\dist\leaflet-src.js:7:65)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\project\react-starterkit\node_modules\leaflet\dist\leaflet-src.js:10:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (D:\project\react-starterkit\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:152:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
```

**Resolved with update react to latest version 16.x**

```
TypeError: (0 , _react.createContext) is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\project\react-starterkit\node_modules\react-leaflet\lib\context.js:18:47)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (D:\project\react-starterkit\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:152:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\project\react-starterkit\node_modules\react-leaflet\lib\index.js:5:16)
```

here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';
import withStyles from 'isomorphic-style-loader/lib/withStyles';
import s from './Home.css';

class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      lat: 51.505,
      lng: -0.09,
      zoom: 13,
    }
  }
  render() {
    const position = [this.state.lat, this.state.lng]
    return (
      <Map center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution="&amp;copy <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <Marker position={position}>
          <Popup>
            A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      </Map>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(s)(Home);
```

**UPDATE 2 Resolved by myself**

```
import React from 'react';
import withStyles from 'isomorphic-style-loader/lib/withStyles';
import leafletCss from '!isomorphic-style-loader!css-loader?modules=false!leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'; //if use isomorphic-style-loader
import s from './GenerateMap.css';

let RL = false;
let Map = false;
let TileLayer = false;
let Marker = false;
let Popup = false;
if (process.env.BROWSER) {
  RL = require('react-leaflet');
  Map = RL.Map;
  TileLayer = RL.TileLayer;
  Marker = RL.Marker;
  Popup = RL.Popup;
}

class GenerateMap extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const position = [51.505, -0.09]

    return (
      <div className={s.root}>
        {process.env.BROWSER && (
          <Map style={{width:'100%',height: '500px'}} center={position} zoom={13}>
            <TileLayer
              url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
              attribution="&copy; <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
            />
            <Marker position={position} icon=''>
              <Popup>A pretty CSS3 popup.<br />Easily customizable.</Popup>
            </Marker>
          </Map>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(s, leafletCss)(GenerateMap);
```

Comment: You get this error on server side ? or in browser ?

Comment: on server side rendering

Comment: you can `return null;` if `typeof window === 'undefined'` so it will render Map only on client side.

Comment: ok i know i can use `typeof` or `process.env.BROWSER` but it's a npm module and i cant change it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the stack traces, I see that `react-leaflet` is using `createContext()` which is part of React Context API. This is only available in [React 16.3](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/29/react-v-16-3.html).

Have you checked the [version](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) of `react-leaflet` you are using? You might be using version that have dependency to React 16.3. You could try downgrading to `react-leaflet` 1.9.1 and see if it works.

Updated answer:

`window` is not defined is an error that most likely happened when your code is trying to access the global variable `window` which is only defined when your code run in browser (not SSR). Check your code to see if that error happened because of your code. If it is caused by `react-leaflet`, read below...

After more searching, it seems that `react-leaflet` isn't built with server side rendering in mind. You could try checking [react-leaflet-universal](https://github.com/masotime/react-leaflet-universal) to implement it. If all else fail, you might need to build your own wrapper for leaflet to achieve this.

Comment: thank you it's correct but now i've this error `ReferenceError: window is not defined`! it's for SSR how can load it for CSR?

Comment: For Client Side Rendering, you have to wait till the component is mounted. I haven't tested this, but I wonder if ComponentDidMount might work.